# Cyclone III FPGA 16x2 LCD repeat one character instead of displaying complete word

Tags: fpga, verilog, lcd, intel-fpga, cyclone

So I am trying to use the LCD on the cyclone III FPGA.
I have written this verilog code that should display numbers 0 to 9 then letters A to G

Compiling the code has no errors at all

However, when loading the code on the board it has weird behavior

The LCD keeps repeating the last character only and keeps printing G across the entire LCD
[image: LCD Repeating Same Letter]

I have tried changing the line `21: data <= 8'h47;      //G` to another letter and it keeps printing that new letter

Also the pin assignments are seemingly correct

It doesn't make sense to me as clearly the initializing part is working correctly

```
            0: data <= 8'h38;   //Function Set: 8-bit, 2 Line, 5x7 Dots
            1: data <= 8'h06;       //Entry Mode
            2: data <= 8'h0C;       //Display on Cursor off
            3: data <= 8'h01;       //Clear Display (also clear DDRAM content)
            4: data <= 8'h80;       //Set DDRAM address or cursor position on display to
```

so why are the characters in the middle not displaying and only last character is displaying

This is the entire code

```
module lcd16x2_v (clk, clr, lcd_rs, lcd_e, data );

input clk, clr;

output reg lcd_rs, lcd_e;
output reg [7:0] data;

integer en_timing;
integer i;

always @ (posedge clk or negedge clr) begin

    if (~clr) begin  //PB0
    
        en_timing = 0;
        i = 0;
        data = 0;
        
    end else begin

        en_timing <= en_timing + 1; 
        
        lcd_rs <= (i <= 5) ? 0 : 1;   // high data input ,, low instr. input
        
        if (en_timing <= 50000) begin
            lcd_e <=1;      //read
            case(i)
            0: data <= 8'h38;   //Function Set: 8-bit, 2 Line, 5x7 Dots
            1: data <= 8'h06;       //Entry Mode
            2: data <= 8'h0C;       //Display on Cursor off
            3: data <= 8'h01;       //Clear Display (also clear DDRAM content)
            4: data <= 8'h80;       //Set DDRAM address or coursor position on display to 
            5: data <= 8'h30;       //0
            6: data <= 8'h31;       //1
            7: data <= 8'h32;       //2
            8: data <= 8'h33;
            9: data <= 8'h34;
            10: data <= 8'h35;
            11: data <= 8'h36;
            12: data <= 8'h37;
            13: data <= 8'h38;
            14: data <= 8'h39;      //9
            15: data <= 8'h41;      //A
            16: data <= 8'h42;      //B
            17: data <= 8'h43;      //C
            18: data <= 8'h44;      //D
            19: data <= 8'h45;      //E
            20: data <= 8'h46;      //F
            21: data <= 8'h47;      //G
            default: data <= 0;
            endcase
        end
        else if (en_timing > 50000 && en_timing < 100000) begin
            lcd_e <= 0;
        end
        else begin
            en_timing <= 0;
            if (i >= 21)  
                i <= 5;
            else 
                i <= i + 1;
        end
    end
end

endmodule
```

I have tries simulating the code  with lower number of cycles (5 instead of 50000 and 10 instead of 100000) to get more insight and it seems to be correct
[image: VWF Simulation]

Comment: Your cycle time is way to fast. E is usually around 1us. Read the datasheet of the lcd controller to find out the required timing.

Comment: i am using a clock of 50 mhz and i am cycling at 50000 count so the timing is 1 ms which the LCD works with......I have also increased the number of cycles to 10 times.......the LCD just repeats the character at slower rate.....so i don't think that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

Many problems.

I believe you set the RS low one byte too late. State 5 is the first ASCII character.

But that's not all, the Clear Display command takes about 1.5 - 2 milliseconds to complete so you should not write anything to it during that time.

Comment: I have tried setting the rs at an earlier state at i =20 instead of i=21.....it repeats the character before the last which is "F".....As for the timing, I am using a clock of 50 mhz and i am cycling at 50000 count so the timing is 1 ms which the LCD works with......I have also increased the number of cycles to 10 times.......the LCD just repeats the character at slower rate.....so i don't think that's the problem